# Mongo and Rails Nested Embeds issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am pretty new to MongoDb and rails but I am setting up a soccer team info site. I have leagues which embeds teams. The teams embed nicknames.

So I have a **routes.rb** which looks like this:

```
resources :leagues do
  resources :teams do
    resources :club_nicknames
  end
end
```

On the team show page I have a form to add a new nickname:

```
%h2 New Nickname
  = form_for [@team, ClubNickname.new] do |f|
    %p
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name
      %p= f.submit
```

But I get this error

```
undefined method `team_club_nicknames_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd58a001970>:0x007fd58a295718>
```

From rake routes I know it should be targeting **league_team_club_nicknames_path** but I can't get it to and I am in a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `@team`'s associated league in the form array:

```
%h2 New Nickname
  = form_for [@team.league, @team, ClubNickname.new] do |f|
    %p
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name
      %p= f.submit
```

(I'm assuming you have a `belongs_to :league` relationship in your `Team` model.)

Comment: Thank you that got me past the error above but now I get a 

`uninitialized constant ClubNicknamesController error`.  

I have a this in my Team model 

`embeds_many :club_nicknames
  embedded_in :league`

Comment: The form needs somewhere to send the data once the form is submitted. By default Rails expects a `ClubNicknamesController`, but you can post the data anywhere. Either create a `club_nicknames_controller.rb` file in your app/controllers directory, or use a `:url` option with the `form_for` tag to specify where to send the data.

Comment: I do have a `ClubNicknamesController` it has in it.
`def create`  
 `@league = League.find(params[:league_id])  `
 `@team = @league.teams.where('_id' => params[:team_id]) ` 
 `@club_nickname = @team.club_nicknames.create!(params[:club_nickname])`  `redirect_to @league, :notice => "Comment created!" ` 
`end`

Comment: Are other actions in the controller working fine, or are there no other actions?

Comment: Try creating a `new` action with no code in it and navigating to the route for that action. (It should be of the format `/leagues/:league_id/teams/:team_id/club_nicknames/new`) Hopefully this will test whether or not the controller is being loaded.

Comment: I get the same uninitialized constant ClubNicknamesController error

Comment: Ok, it seems like the controller is not being loaded properly. Where is your controller, and are you sure it is named properly?

Comment: I missed the s of the controller name and classname. ClubNicknameController not ClubNicknamesController Such a stupid error.  I can't thank you enough for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for thanking me, and have fun with Rails! :D